# How do I get this Python code to output only one line?

Tags: python, list, printing, append

I'm new to this site. I have a piece of code (shown below) and I'm having trouble returning the output I want.

```
list = [(10, 10)]
for i in range (0, 3):
    for j in range (0, 3):
        pair = (i, j)
        list.append(pair)
        print(list)
```

I want to print only the list with all pairs, i.e. `[(10, 10), (0, 0), (0, 1), ..., (2, 2)]`.
However, when you run the code, it ouputs all lists after each successive pair is added, i.e.

```
[(10, 10), (0, 0)]
[(10, 10), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
[(10, 10), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
```

..., etc.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove the `print` from the nested loops and place it at the end i.e. remove all its indentation

Answer (score 0):

Your `print(list)` is put inside the loop, causing it to be executed on each iteration, you can put it outside the loop,then it will executed only once.
PS:It's not a good idea to name your variables with the same name as the builtins, you can use `l` instead of `list`
Fixed code:

```py
l = [(10, 10)]
for i in range (0, 3):
    for j in range (0, 3):
        pair = (i, j)
        l.append(pair)
print(l)
```